# A function returns string "null" from the CoordinatesZ2.Text even if it contains value

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making a tool in C# using Windows Forms with .NET Framework 4.7.1.0 which does math calculations for game Minecraft making building and calculating process easier and faster.

I made a button "Calculate Field" with in-code name `CalculateFieldButton` which is supposed to calculate a field of a rectangle based on two Coordinates inputs, which I made using `TextBox` components inside separate `GroupBox` component.

App look screenshot:
[image: Click here]

```cs
//Code activated after clicking on a button.
private void CalculateFieldButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        intCoordinatesX = Convert.ToInt32(CoordinatesX);
        intCoordinatesZ = Convert.ToInt32(CoordinatesZ);
        intCoordinatesX2 = Convert.ToInt32(CoordinatesX2);
        intCoordinatesZ2 = Convert.ToInt32(CoordinatesZ2);

        NetherErrorLabel.Visible = false;

        field = (intCoordinatesX - intCoordinatesX2) * (intCoordinatesZ - intCoordinatesZ2);

        FieldLabel.Text = "Field: " + Convert.ToString(field);
    } catch (FormatException)
    {
        //shows error text when the format of the numbers is wrong.
        NetherErrorLabel.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

For example:

```
CoordinatesX = 16
CoordinatesZ = 16
CoordinatesX2 = 8
CoordinatesZ2 = 8
```

Putting everything into formula gives me:

```
(16 - 8) * (16 - 8)
```

which should be equal to 64, but the output is 128 instead. (I know about negative values, but I'll do them once I'll fix this problem.)

After running program in debug mode and going through each line I've noticed, that `CoordinatesZ2` string is `null` even though it contains a value, and using function `Convert.ToInt32()`; with argument `null` returns 0, and then it leads to the wrong result. The rest of the values are parsed correctly. Here are the screenshots of the Debug session when it converts `CoordinatesZ2` to integer and a section of code which takes values from TextBoxes:

Debug: [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYAy9.png) [Second link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bmm9v.png)

```cs
private void InputBoxX_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) => CoordinatesX = InputBoxX.Text; 
private void InputBoxY_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) => CoordinatesY = InputBoxY.Text;
private void InputBoxZ_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) => CoordinatesZ = InputBoxZ.Text;
private void InputBoxX2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) => CoordinatesX2 = InputBoxX2.Text;
private void InputBoxY2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) => CoordinatesY2 = InputBoxY2.Text;
private void InputBoxZ2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) => CoordinatesZ2 = InputBoxZ2.Text;
```

I honestly don't know why this occurs and I never had similar problem like this never before. I checked properties of TextBoxes, syntax and I can't work out how to fix this. If you need any other information which you would need to get feel free to write. Also you can give feedback. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please check if your event InputBoxZ2_TextChanged is triggered at all? You can find this in the properties tool window. Select the TextBox and click on the lightning icon, then search for TextChanged and double click if empty.

Comment: @PhilippApe It was empty. After double clicking it created another function. I commented the old one and copypasted the code from the old fucntion to the newly created one and it actually worked. Thanks for help!

Comment: Why don't you simply read the text from the TextBox Controls instead of adding all those event handlers? Use `int.TryParse()` to validate the input.

Comment: @Jimi Yeah, I cloud do that instead. I'm still learning though. Thanks for feedback